# Sharing data between async requests in Tokio

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

EDIT: I refactored the code to make it simpler.

I'm writing a small program to check a website for dead links, using tokio and reqwests to make requests async without the need for threading. But I also need to be able to return something from each of the requests that tokio is running; namely if a request failed or not.

```rust
fn fetch(req: Vec<&'static str>) {
    let client = Client::new();
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let req_len = req.len();
    let work = stream::iter_ok(req)
        .map(move |url| client.get(url).send())
        .buffer_unordered(PARALLEL_REQUESTS)
        .then(move |response| {
            let this_tx = tx.clone();
            match response {
                Ok(x) => {
                    format_response(x);

                    this_tx.send(1).unwrap();
                }

                Err(x) => {
                    format_error(x);
                }
            }

            future::ok(())
        })
        .for_each(|n| Ok(()));

    tokio::run(work);
```

The code works, but I'd like some feedback as to what the best way of writing this in Rust would be.

Comment: _"namely if a request failed or not"_ Have you tried yielding a `Result` from the future?

Comment: How would I do that?
I refactored the code to get rid of the odd wrapping a stream in a stream and then flattening it, a .then() does the job. But ideally, it should be possible to do something like mapping a function to an array with the return values. In python this can be done using a threadpool (Not async, but still) and .map, but in rust I have no idea